# Cannot destructure property 'executor' of 'auditlogs' as it is undefined. discord.js channelUpdate event

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am creating a discord bot and I am using the channelUpdate event
whenever I try to get something from the logs in this event it just says that auditlogs is not defined even tho it works with other events for me.
So if anyone can help me and give me a way to get the executor I would appreciate it!

My code:

```
    const fetchedLogs = await oldChannel.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
        limit: 1,
        type: "CHANNEL_UPDATE"
    });
    console.log(oldChannel.guild.id)
    auditlogs = fetchedLogs.entries.first()
    const { executor } = auditlogs
    console.log(executor.tag)
});
```

Error I get

> const { executor } = auditlogs
>
> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'executor' of 'auditlogs' as it is undefined.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. either `auditlogs` or `executor` is undefined, so find out which one it is and why. My guess is that `auditlogs` is undefined.

Comment: Just use `console.log` on both `auditlogs` and `auditlogs.executor`, and you will know which one is undefined. It indeed probably is `auditlogs` that is undefined, because a `channelUpdate` event usually does have an executor. The problem is probably because you are trying to fetch the audit log entry for the channel update immediately after the event itself occurs, so your code will either not be able to find the specific entry since it may not have been made yet, or it will try to fetch an older entry. You might want to delay fetching the audit log entry by a few seconds using a timeout.

Comment: auditlogs.executor gives an error and audit logs is undefined
so what should I do now to fix this thing

Comment: I have tried the timeout function but it gives the same results so idk what should I do
this is the first time trying to use the channelUpdate event tbh
I think the constant fetchedlogs is the problem since it doesn't give me options when writing the type of the audit log unlike the others it gives me a big list of types of audit logs